# Encryption and Decryption in javascript and c# add password filed in c# code

Tags: javascript, encryption, passwords

I found this code in c#. Its a dummy question but I don't know anything about encryption. This code encrypt and decrypt but there is no password field where should I put. This is the code that I found which is compatible with the java-script code so I really want it to work at last. Thank you :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Diagnostics;

using System.IO;
namespace Rextester
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "Please enter UserName";

            var encry = EncryptStringAES(s);
            var dec = DecryptStringAES(encry);


            Console.WriteLine(encry);
            Console.WriteLine(dec);

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }







  public static string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText)
        {
            var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("8080808080808080");
            var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("8080808080808080");

            var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            var decriptedFromJavascript = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, keybytes, iv);
            return string.Format(decriptedFromJavascript);
        } 
        private static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // Check arguments.  
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            }
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }
            if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }

            // Declare the string used to hold  
            // the decrypted text.  
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an RijndaelManaged object  
            // with the specified key and IV.  
            using (var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                //Settings  
                rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                rijAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;

                rijAlg.Key = key;
                rijAlg.IV = iv;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.  
                var decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                try
                {
                    // Create the streams used for decryption.  
                    using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                    {
                        using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {

                            using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                            {
                                // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream  
                                // and place them in a string.  
                                plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    plaintext = "keyError";
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }

        public static string EncryptStringAES(string plainText)
        {
            var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("8080808080808080");
            var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("8080808080808080");

            var encryoFromJavascript = EncryptStringToBytes(plainText, keybytes, iv);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryoFromJavascript);
        }  


        private static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // Check arguments.  
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            }
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }
            if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create a RijndaelManaged object  
            // with the specified key and IV.  
            using (var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                rijAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;

                rijAlg.Key = key;
                rijAlg.IV = iv;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.  
                var encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.  
                using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.  
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.  
            return encrypted;
        }

}


}
```

The java-script I know where to put the password but in c# I don't know:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js "></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function SubmitsEncry() {

        debugger;
        var txtUserName = "Please enter UserName";

        var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');
        var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');

        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(txtUserName),'1', key,
        {
            keySize: 128 / 8,
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted,'1', key,
           {
               keySize: 128 / 8,
               iv: iv,
               mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
               padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
           });
        alert(encrypted);
    }
    SubmitsEncry();


    </script>
```

Comment: Do you think that, if you know nothing about encryption and cryptography, it is a good idea for you to be implementing it and using it?  Additionally, if you are using this code to encrypt communications between your Javascript application/website and your C# server, then you are doing things very very wrong.  Use TLS/HTTPS instead.  Also note that the code you do have is exceptionally insecure and trivially broken if you are using it for what I said above.

Comment: i need client encryption  i found tools like staticrypt  but i need to customized like i want so i want to create program in c# to encrypt part of multi HTML files and then decrypted it by java-script with crypto-js i know i have many ststic html files i need part of them to be protected with encryption only

Comment: Let me phrase it this way, because I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're saying you need:  Why can't you use HTTPS?

Comment: if you mean online protection no i want offline protection to generate compiled HTML books ..without using net

Comment: Okay...  So is the Javascript in the HTML file going to be used to decrypt the portions of HTML that are encrypted?  It is "self-contained"?  Where is the Javascript code?

Comment: no the c# tool will encrypt part of the HTML page and then the java-script that add to HTML page will decrypted the page must be protected with password:
check this example :https://robinmoisson.github.io/staticrypt/example.html

Comment: but i have hundred of HTML pages i cant do it manually so i need c# program to do the jop .. also  i want to customized to work with old browser like ie6 + my issue here only just how to put password filed in c# code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the extent of your question, but if it is as simple as it appears to be, you could always Ctrl-F to find the key in the C# code.  It's the line that starts with `var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("80...`

However, the code that you have isn't going to do what you want.  It is insecure and easily broken (since the key is literally **in** the code).  Your lack of understanding of cryptography in general is also going to limit your ability to create the solution I think you are envisioning.

Some advice:

- If you want to use a password, you need to understand that this is fundamentally different from a key.  Use a KDF to derive a key from a password.  PBKDF2 is good.
- Don't use a fixed IV.  If the IV remains the same then you compromise the encryption.  It should be different every time you encrypt.  It doesn't need to be secret at all, just different.
- Use an authenticated mode if you can (GCM), otherwise use an HMAC to authenticate your ciphertext.  If you don't do this, anyone can change the contents of the file (even if it is encrypted) and you won't know that this has happened.

I recommend you view the examples in [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples).  There are examples for both C# and browser JavaScript.